# Print Array values for get_post_custom_values

Tags: php, wordpress

I have started learning php, specifically for wordpress.

I want to get print out the value of a custom field:

```
<?php echo get_post_custom_values("Gear",get_the_ID()); ?>
```

I  get `Array` back.

Any suggestions how to print all values of the array or show only the first value?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get_post_custom_values return the array of values associated with that key.
You need to use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to print the array

```
<?php print_r(get_post_custom_values("Gear",get_the_ID())); ?>
```

Or use `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Gear', true);` to print the single value as string. Passing the third parameter as true return the single value for that key.

Check here [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: Thx for your answer! For `<?php echo var_dump(get_post_meta($post_id, 'Gear', true)); ?>` I get `bool(false)`. For print_r I get `1`. For `<?php print_r(get_post_custom_values("Gear",get_the_ID())); ?>` I get `Array
(
    [0] => afasdfasdf
)
`. Any suggestions how to get only the value `afasdfasdf`?

Comment: Ok I tried `echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Gear', true);`, which works perfectly ;)  Thx for your help!

Comment: $post_id has been used as example replace it with get_the_id(). Editing the answer. :)